# Nesting image elements inside of a div is causing them to overflow a flex container instead of scrolling

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I nested a bunch of mapped img elements within a div and set the div's `overflow-x` to scroll.

```
<div className='w-full px-2 flex gap-2 overflow-x-scroll scrollbar-none'>
  {props?.categoryMovies?.map((movie, i)=> (
    <img 
       id={movie?.id}
       key={i}
       className='w-[60] h-[60] object-contain'
       src={props?.preImg + movie?.poster_path} 
    />
           
  ))}
</div>
```

As expected, when I run this code, any img element that flows outside the barrier of the parent div's width is only visible when I scroll along the x-axis.

However, when I try to nest those img elements inside of another div, the behavior changes.

```
<div className='w-full px-2 flex gap-2 overflow-x-scroll scrollbar-none'>
  {props?.categoryMovies?.map((movie, i)=> (
    <div className='w-60 h-60'>
      <img 
        id={movie?.id}
        key={i}
        className='w-full h-full object-contain'
        src={props?.preImg + movie?.poster_path} />
    </div>
  ))}
</div>
```

Instead of maintaining the same results, content that flows out of the main parent div element is visible by default. So, you can say it's as if it breaks out of the barrier of the parent div element and is visible when I scroll on any part of the body of the page, not just when I scroll on the parent container div.

How can I get the second code block to behave like my initial example and have the content become visible only when I scroll on the parent div container?

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix this would be to give each `<div>` in your flexbox the utility class `flex-shrink-0`, which will preserve the size of each container.

```
<div className="w-full px-2 flex gap-2 overflow-x-scroll scrollbar-none">
  {props?.categoryMovies?.map((movie, i)=> (
      <div className="w-60 h-60 flex-shrink-0">
      <img id="{movie?.id}" key="{i}" className="w-full h-full object-contain" src={props?.preImg + movie?.poster_path} />
    </div>
  ))}
</div>
```

You can see it working here: https://play.tailwindcss.com/KoEroV1coQ

Comment: thanks a lot but it still didn't work

Comment: Sorry, there were some stray quotation marks in the image `src` after reformatting. Was that it, or is there some difference in the final markup that your JSX is rendering that's different than my working Tailwind Playground version?